# How to update my Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, updates, desktop-environments

I am running Ubuntu GNOME and I want to upgrade to another stable (if possible) version.

Right now I'm running GNOME Shell 3.18.5.

Last time when I upgraded everything was broken.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 offers gnome-shell 3.18.5 right now, so if you willing to stick with default sources you are on the latest version.

Comment: @dufte so there is no safe way to upgrade it?

Comment: You could for sure use the ppa of the gnome3-team. You'll find some details on how to here: http://www.webupd8.org/2016/04/how-to-install-gnome-320-in-ubuntu.html. Regarding safe or not: consider browsing/reading the comment section on webupd8 to get a better impressions of potential risks. I would stick with default sources in case of Ubuntu. If you really feel in need to get latest versions asap i would consider using another distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu GNOME 16.10** will be released **October 13**. It features GNOME 3.20 with many apps upgraded to 3.22. Since non-LTS releases are only supported for 9 months, you'll need to upgrade more frequently until the next LTS.

Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 is currently in [Beta](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/Beta2/UbuntuGNOME).